# Will I always get notifications from other users with same user name

Tags: bug, chat

I've been using the Javascript chat page on SO. Clearly, so has another user with the same username `Dave`.

When I log onto one of the SE sites first thing in the morning I often see I have notifications yet often though these are not intended for me.

Whilst I don't have an issue with not being popular, getting the notifications are annoying as  have to go through them all. One day, there were 7 - none intended for me.

My latest message was this morning, clicking it took me to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19599814#19599814

The 15th or 16th post up from the bottom has the @Dave but, that Dave is not me! I wish it was, the user seems to be doing some amazing things, but ultimately, it isn't. Actually, I doubt he plays guitar as well as I do, so I'm happy to stay as me on second thoughts.

Is there a way to turn off these 'incorrect' (unintended) notifications or am I stuck with it and need to find a unique name?

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that

Comment: On a more serious note, I think the system is inherently flawed here. Allowing duplicate usernames was a mistake in the first place for this exact reason, but I would be surprised if SE decided to change it now. Picking a unique name is probably the best solution.

Comment: I can't speak for chat, but if the `@`-replies in comments work the same way, then the system is design to ping the last user who commented who matches the first 3 letters of the Display Name.  So if 2 users named `Dave` and `Davidson` where active on a question, the `Dav...` that commented last will be notified when someone pings them.